# How to get started with Vulkan with AMD Richland [Radeon HD 8610G] Card

Tags: vulkan

I'm wondering what is the best way to get started developing with Vulkan on my laptop. My GPU is an AMD Richland [Radeon HD 8610G]. I was wondering if any of the available drivers have support for my card, and if it is supported what I need to install to allow developing programs that use Vulkan.

scipio

Answer (score 1):

[based on this reference](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/vulkan), your card should be supported.

The group behind Vulkan have put together a [beginners guide](https://www.khronos.org/blog/beginners-guide-to-vulkan), I'd suggest starting there.
It should hopefully answer all of your questions.